# Error al renovar credenciales de mercadopago connect

Tags: mercadopago

hace ya un par de años que estamos usando para gestionar los pagos de nuestra plataforma mercadopago connect. Hasta ahora el proceso de conectar usuarios [1] y renovacion de credenciales [2] venia funcionando a la perfeccion, pero desde hace un tiempo dejo de funcionar dando errores como

```
Error validating grant. Your authorization code or refresh token may be expired or it was already used.
```

O directamente

```
invalid_token
```

Entiendo que el primer error deberia darmelo si ya use el token para intentar una renovacion, pero no es el caso, y el segundo error no dice mucho mas.

A alguien le esta suciediendo lo mismo? saben si hubo algun cambio no ducumentado en la API.

Gracias

[1] https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/mercadopago-connect/#connect-users

[2] https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/mercadopago-connect/#renew-credentials

Comment: nos está pasando lo mismo, pudieron identificar la causa?

Comment: Hola Lautaro, ¿Ya preguntaron a soporte de la compañía en cuestión? , recuerda que las preguntas deben realizarse en base a [ask]. Con respecto a tu pregunta te sugiero revisar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%C3%A9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%C3%B1%C3%ADa-favorita